# load data in file, on duplicate of primary key update columns from csv file

Tags: mysql, sql-update, load-data-infile

I have a table name list_subscriber, I also have few records with there primary keys available(all records are in csv file and it is considered that these are updated records), so in case if there is any duplicate found based on primary key in csv file, then that particular records should go for update in list_subscriber table.

For which I am considering load data in file syntax, but I am unable to make query.

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE '/home/abhishek/deploy/file_uploaded/abhishekupdate.csv' INTO TABLE list_subscriber 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '`' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 0 LINES (id,list_master_id,unique_identifier)  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..;
```

I have also tried update query using two tables but it stops/hangs for 10 Lacks of records as table is big in structure.

Any help is appreciated.